# API Apps published to the same resource group are not appearning in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I created a brand new Logic App in a new Resource group called Workflows. I also published a new API APP (using VS 2015 and SDK 2.82 the latest) to the same resource group.

When I list the App Services, I see my new Api APP listed with a type of Api App as expected. Also when I list the resource group items, I see my logic app and my API app.

The problem is when I edit the logic app (Triggers and Actions), my new API APP does not appear under Workflows resource group. Hence I can't use it in my Logic app.

In the past (two months ago) prior to App Services renaming, this used to work and I did create logic apps with my API apps. It is really frustrating now.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I am facing exactly same issue with new version of API Apps, they just don't appear in Logic App designer

Answer (score 2):

The Logic Apps designer will be adding especially seamless integration with the new API Apps model in early 2016. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-whats-changed/

so new API Apps won't appear in Logic Apps Preview designer till next Logic Apps release

Answer (score 1):

With the latest release of the Preview LogicApp, there is an action "Http + Swagger" where you can enter the swagger docs uri of your custom api app. It will list all the actions from your api and you can create a workflow.

Steps -
On your custom api app enable CORS and use **"https"** uri in the logic app "Http + Swagger" action.

This is just a work-around I am suggesting. I tried it myself :)

Comment: Thank you! While this is an improvement, are we going to get the custom API Apps to just appear in the designer (as steps) as they used to? Also...I have an API App that provides push triggers....how would this work with just an HTTP + Swagger? In any case, I have not tried the new release. Hopefully I will soon and re-comment. Thanks.

Comment: @KhaledHikmat checkout this link for the customapi with trigger https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-create-api-app/